# Downloading a file clicking a link or button on a jquery dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, download, jquery-ui-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download a file using jQuery after creating it in the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954657/download-a-file-using-jquery-after-creating-it-in-the-server)

I have a jQueryUI dialog which contains some HTML content. After user makes their input and clicks the OK button a call to the server is established with AJAX. Inside the referenced static method a file is created based on the user input. After the file is created the user should be able to download it. How do I achieve this? I've heard about "creating a form in that dialog where the action is POSTing to the server but I have no idea how to do this.

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954657/download-a-file-using-jquery-after-creating-it-in-the-server/13958836#13958836) covers the server side of the same issue.

Comment: Have the button submit to an iframe rather than making an ajax request. Oh, that's what i suggested yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954657/download-a-file-using-jquery-after-creating-it-in-the-server/13958836#13958836

Comment: Dear Kevin, I know you suggested that, but unfortunately I found it difficult to implement and now I've heard about creating a form in the dialog. Is this form the iframe you were talking about? :)

Comment: Yes, however, the code in my answer actually generates the form for you. All you would need to do is modify this line to include the data that you want to send to the server. `form.append('<input type="hidden" name="somename">').val("someval");`

Comment: OK, Kev, I got it. I promise that I won't show up with this question anymore. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your AJAX call create the file and store it on the server somewhere. In the `success` handler of your AJAX call, set the source of an `iframe` on your page to the URL of the created file.